# Convert Ninject Modules to Autofac

Tags: c#, ninject, autofac

I'm learning now .NetCore and Autofac and I have a doubt about how to convert Ninject Modules to Autofac Modules.

Let's see some code:

Module:

```
using Ninject.Modules;

namespace v0.CrossCutting.Ninject.Domain.Data
{
    using v0.Domain.Data.Model.Interfaces;
    using v0.Domain.Data.Model.Classes;

    public class Model : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            try
            {
                Bind<IConfig>().To<Config>();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Register:

```
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Modules;

namespace v0.CrossCutting.Ninject
{
    public static class Container
    {
        private static IKernel Kernel;

        static Container()
        {
            INinjectModule[] NinjectModules = new INinjectModule[]
            {
                new Domain.Data.Model()
            };

            Kernel = new StandardKernel(NinjectModules);
        }

        public static TModel Resolve<TModel>()
        {
            try
            {
                return Kernel.Get<TModel>();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I searched on internet and another stack overflow questions but I still couldn't figure it out how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question implies you are spreading out your bindings over all the projects in your application, while [only the start-up project should know about the container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Comment: it's a DDD with a cross cutting layer. I'll test @tdragon answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autofac Modules are described in Autofac [documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/modules.html). I am not very familiar with Ninject, but it seems you are trying to achieve something like this:

The module class must implement Autofac's `Module` class and override `Load` method, similarly to Ninject:

```
public class ModelModule : Module
{
    public override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<Config>().As<IConfig>();
    }
}
```

Later on, you have to register your module within container itself:

```
public class ContainerConfig
{
    public IContainer ConfigureAutofac()
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new ModelModule());

        return containerBuilder.Build();
    }
}
```

Btw, static `Container` class with public and static `Resolve` method is considered an anti-pattern and should be avoided.